# Is "lower pressurization" the correct term for the 787 Dreamliner?

Tags: terminology

In this blog, the FA refers to the 787 Dreamliner as having "lower pressurization":

http://theflightattendantlife.com/the-boeing-787-8-a-flight-attendant-takes-you-on-an-inside-tour-of-the-dreamliner/

The Dreamliner has higher air-pressure in the cabin due to its fuselage construction -- but this **higher** air-pressure makes the perceived 'altitude' **lower**.

Is the correct (air transport) term for this "lower pressurization" or "higher pressurization" or is there a better third alternative??

Comment: Neither. Both ways it is confusing.

Comment: I take it as an error - probably confusion between "higher cabin pressure" and "lower cabin pressure altitude". Maybe it was originally written as "lower cabin pressurization altitude" and someone decided it was too wordy or sounded too technical and simply dropped words without understanding how the change affected meaning.

Comment: I'd say that it depends on the official unit used to measure cabin "pressurization" (meter or pascal), if there is one. But this seems undefined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The terminology is confusing. When you say lower or higher, it is better to clarify the reference.

Boeing 787 has a [*higher cabin pressure*](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/does-the-b787-dreamliner-operate-with-higher-cabin-pressure) compared to the legacy airliners.

The best way to say it is that it is pressurized to (or has) a lower cabin altitude compared to other airliners.